# Align two buttons horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I have two buttons and I want to put them horizontally so the screen they will be beside each other, there is not space left, I know I can do it with linearlayout and set weight but I want relativelayout because I already have weight in my XML so it will be bad performance to put two weights in each other.

I tried like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_send"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/b_send"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_cancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/b_cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But just the cancel button is appeard and that is because I used "fill parent", what is the solution please?

Comment: use Linear Layout with Horizontal Orientation

Comment: and how can i make the buttons occupy all the aviable space please ?

Comment: I'll post the answer wait

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try add to your code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector" >


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_send"

           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
    ....
    />

     <View 
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_cancel"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
    ...
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the button's width should stay "fill parent" ?

Comment: yes  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: i will accept your asnwer after 10 mins

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
     <Button
           android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please i told you that i dont want to use linearlayout and i don't want to user weight,

Comment: he give me the answer , +1 to you thanks

Comment: This worked great for me.